# How to create single HTTPS route in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, https, routes

Example from documentation not working :

```
route_name:
path:  /dropbox/connect/return/{params}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeDropboxBundle:Dropbox:redirect}
schemes:  [https]
```

When I go to https://local.acme.com/dropbox/connect/return/something I getting 404 Not Found.

EDIT : 
I'm also tried with configuration in the security config :

```
- { path: ^/dropbox/connect/return/, role: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
```

Comment: Does it work when you try it in dev with `/app_dev.php/dropbox/...`? Have you cleared the cache since changing the route and security.yml?

Comment: I am already in dev mode and cleared cache just to be sure, but still not working

Comment: One more thing to mention. ssl module is enabled on my apache.

Comment: If you are in dev mode then how come you are not going to `https://local.acme.com/app_dev.php/dropbox/connect/return/something`?

Comment: In virtual host settings I was put DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

Comment: Have you define a custom htaccess for dev or/and prod mode? If yes, provide us your customization

Comment: I said in my previous comment. In my virtual host DirectoryIndex is app_dev.php instead app.php

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with my ssl configuration.

In default-ssl i added configuration from my virtual host and then is working well.